# Simple Number Theory Identity Regarding Subtraction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Take these two digit numbers:
$$xa$$
$$yb$$

Assume $$x>y>0$$ and $$b>a>=0$$ and we are to subtract the two numbers. If for example we set, a=3 and b=6, the unit digit of this subtraction will always be 7, regardless of what x and y are. I want to know if there is an identity that can help you identify the unit digit of a subtraction or a shortcut that can help you realize the third number by simply glancing without a thought. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, you asked How to recognize the unit digit of the result of a subtraction right?

Answer (score 2):

Given the conditions for two, 2-digit numbers:

$$xa,\quad yb , \quad x> y > 0, \quad b > a \geq 0,$$

we can simply recognize that the unit's digit of the difference $\,xa - yb,\;$will be given by $$10 - (b - a) = 10 + a - b$$ But that's what we do, implicitly, when mechanically subtracting the given two digit numbers.

Put differently, we can express the unit's digit of the difference first by finding $(a - b) \pmod {10}$, which will necessarily be negative, so to find the desired positive unit's digit, we'd simply add $10$.

Comment: Please clarify if I misunderstood what you are asking.

Comment: Hi amWhy. Thank you for responding to my question. I was wondering if there was mental math type identity that could be used to identify our third digit (the unit digit) quickly. {3,6,7};{5,8,7};{4,7,7}, etc. But it seems the only way to be super quick at subtraction of 4-5 digit numbers is to memorize that {3,6,7}.

Comment: You could use the trick above $\{3, 6, 10+3-6= 7\}, \;\{5, 8, 10+5-8 = 7\},$ etc....

Comment: @amWhy: I wonder if the OP got it? +1

Comment: Not quite sure...Oh well, we can hope. ;-)

Comment: amWhy, I completely understand you, believe me I do. But reducing the problem to 10+3(13)-6. Goes back to the same problem where you have two numbers (13)-(06). I was only wondering if there was a quicker way to recognize that the triplet was (3,6,7), (5,7,8),(6,8,8), etc.

Comment: for example, in the triplet (3,6,7), you can subtract a 10 from the middle number 6 to arrive at 4. which you add the first number 3, to arrive at 7. Again, I am really sorry, I know what am asking is basic but the reality is, in your example, when you did (10+3-6). You did 10+3=13. Now subtract 6 from 13. Well, how did you know 13-6 is 7? You recalled it from your subconscious memory. Why is 13-6=7, in your mind it just is. I trying to train to subtract 6-7 digit numbers in my head and I am trying to find quick tricks to subtract because I am great at adding, horrible at subtracting.